# Hours of operation input form

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, datetime

I need some comments on the code that I "assembled". I want to know if it is efficient because I intend to use it on a live site.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ace6h/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="hourForm">
<div id="Monday-Friday" class="day"></div>
<div id="Saturday" class="day"></div>
<div id="Sunday" class="day"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.day').each(function() {
    var day = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).append('<div id="label">' + day + ': </div>')
    .append('<select id="' + day + 'FromH" name="' + day + 'FromH" class="hour from"></select>')
    .append('<select id="' + day + 'FromM" name="' + day + 'FromM" class="min from"></select>')
    .append(' to <select id="' + day + 'ToH" name="' + day + 'ToH" class="hour to"></select>')
    .append('<select id="' + day + 'ToM" name="' + day + 'ToM" class="min to"></select>')
    .append(' <input type="checkbox" id="closed_' + day + '" name="closed" value="closed" class="closed" /> <label for="closed_' + day + '">Closed</label>');
});

$('.hour').each(function() {
    for (var h = 0; h < 24; h++) {
        $(this).append('<option value="' + h + '">' + h + '</option>');
    }

    $(this).filter('.from').val('6');
    $(this).filter('.to').val('22');
});

$('.min').each(function() {
    var min = [':00', ':15', ':30', ':45'];
    for (var m = 0; m < min.length; m++) {
        $(this).append('<option value="' + min[m] + '">' + min[m] + '</option>');
    }

    $(this).val(':00');
    $(this).filter('.from').val(':30');
});


$('input').change(function() {
    if ($(this).filter(':checked').val() == "closed") {
        $(this).siblings('select').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('select').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});

$('#Sunday .closed').val(["closed"]).siblings('select').attr('disabled', true);


function displayVals() {
    var MondayFridayFromHValues = $("#Monday-FridayFromH").val();
    var MondayFridayFromMValue = $("#Monday-FridayFromM").val();
    var MondayFridayToHValue = $("#Monday-FridayToH").val();
    var MondayFridayToMValue = $("#Monday-FridayToM").val();
    var MondayFridayClosedValue = $("#closed_Monday-Friday").filter(":checked").val();

    if (MondayFridayClosedValue == "closed") {
        var MondayFridayOpen = "Closed";
    }
    else {
        var MondayFridayOpen = MondayFridayFromHValues + MondayFridayFromMValue + "-" + MondayFridayToHValue + MondayFridayToMValue;
    }

    var SaturdayFromHValues = $("#SaturdayFromH").val();
    var SaturdayFromMValue = $("#SaturdayFromM").val();
    var SaturdayToHValue = $("#SaturdayToH").val();
    var SaturdayToMValue = $("#SaturdayToM").val();
    var SaturdayClosedValue = $('#closed_Saturday').filter(':checked').val();

    if (SaturdayClosedValue == "closed") {
        var SaturdayOpen = "Closed";
    }
    else {
        var SaturdayOpen = SaturdayFromHValues + SaturdayFromMValue + "-" + SaturdayToHValue + SaturdayToMValue;
    }

    var SundayFromHValues = $("#SundayFromH").val();
    var SundayFromMValue = $("#SundayFromM").val();
    var SundayToHValue = $("#SundayToH").val();
    var SundayToMValue = $("#SundayToM").val();
    var SundayClosedValue = $('#closed_Sunday').filter(':checked').val();

    if (SundayClosedValue == "closed") {
        var SundayOpen = "Closed";
    }
    else {
        var SundayOpen = SundayFromHValues + SundayFromMValue + "-" + SundayToHValue + SundayToMValue;
    }

    if (MondayFridayOpen == SaturdayOpen) {
        if (MondayFridayOpen == SundayOpen) {
            $("input:text[name='entry.7.group.other_option_']").val("Monday-Sunday: " + MondayFridayOpen);
        }
        else {
            $("input:text[name='entry.7.group.other_option_']").val("Monday-Saturday: " + MondayFridayOpen + ", Sunday: " + SundayOpen);
        }
    }
    else if (MondayFridayOpen != SaturdayOpen && SaturdayOpen == SundayOpen) {
        $("input:text[name='entry.7.group.other_option_']").val("Monday-Friday: " + MondayFridayOpen + ", Saturday-Sunday: " + SaturdayOpen);
    }
    else {
        $("input:text[name='entry.7.group.other_option_']").val("Monday-Friday: " + MondayFridayOpen + ", Saturday: " + SaturdayOpen + ", Sunday: " + SundayOpen);
    }
}
$("div#hourForm select").change(function() {
    $("input:radio[name='entry.7.group']:nth(3)").attr("checked", true);
});

$(":checkbox[name='closed']").change(function() {
    $("input:radio[name='entry.7.group']:nth(3)").attr("checked", true);
});

$("input:text[name='entry.7.group.other_option_']").click(function () {
    $("input:radio[name='entry.7.group']:nth(3)").attr("checked", true);
});

$("div#hourForm select").change(displayVals);
$(":checkbox[name='closed']").change(displayVals);
displayVals();​
```

Comment: Hmm, at least the first part of your code ("building" select elements) shouldn't be done in JavaScript like that, but should be part of the static HTML, possibly generated using a server-side script.

Comment: @RoToRa - Can you help me do it?

Comment: @m1r0 Help doing what? Generate the HTML server-side? That would depend on the language and templating engine you use. And it would be off topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some quick tips;

1. [Look at caching `$(this)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857317/does-it-make-sense-to-jquery-cache-this-ie-this-this). You're regularly re-creating a jQuery object that doesn't change.
2. Adhere to the [common JavaScript coding conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211795/are-there-any-coding-standards-for-javascript); normally a variable that starts with a capital letter denotes a constructor (that should be invoked with `new`). Change all your `SaturdayFromHValues` etc variable names to `saturdayFromHValues`
3. As [mentioned by @priteaes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/10558/12315), you should save the HTML you're constructing to a string and write it to the element once. DOM manipulation is slow, and the browser will be re-paining the window with each `append()` you're using;

   ```
   $(this).append('<div id="label">' + day + ': </div>')
       .append('<select id="' + day + 'FromH" name="' + day + 'FromH" class="hour from"></select>')
       .append('<select id="' + day + 'FromM" name="' + day + 'FromM" class="min from"></select>')
   ```

   Becomes:

   ```
   var html = '';
   html += '<div id="label">' + day + ': </div>';
   html += '<select id="' + day + 'FromH" name="' + day + 'FromH" class="hour from"></select>';
   html += '<select id="' + day + 'FromM" name="' + day + 'FromM" class="min from"></select>';

   $(this).append(html);
   ```

Comment: Great answer Matt, thank you! Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m1r0/Ace6h/27/ . How can I add the other `each` to the `append(html)`?

Comment: @m1ro: I wouldn't worry *toooo* much about getting *each* `each` into exactly **1** `append()`. What I'd change next would be the `appends()` in the `for` loops as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Ace6h/29/

Comment: Here is the final form: http://jsfiddle.net/m1r0/Ace6h/31/ . I learned a lot. Thanks again for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

In the first and second `each`, I would build the entire HTML first (as a string), and then `append()` once.

**Update:**

I prefer something like this:

```
$('.day').each(function() { 
    var day = $(this).attr('id'); 
    var html = '<div id="label">' + day + ': </div>' +
           '<select id="' + day + 'FromH" name="' + day + 'FromH" class="hour from"></select>' +
           '<select id="' + day + 'FromM" name="' + day + 'FromM" class="min from"></select>' + 
           ' to <select id="' + day + 'ToH" name="' + day + 'ToH" class="hour to"></select>' +
           '<select id="' + day + 'ToM" name="' + day + 'ToM" class="min to"></select>' +
           ' <input type="checkbox" id="closed_' + day + '" name="closed" value="closed" class="closed" /> <label for="closed_' + 
               day + '">Closed</label>';

    $(this).append(html);
});
```